# jQuery - Rename elements

Tags: jquery

Got a div whose ID="cartArea" in there I have mulitple textbox

```
<input type="text" id="tb_1" name="tb_1" />
<input type="text" id="tb_2" name="tb_2" />
<input type="text" id="tb_3" name="tb_3" />
```

and so on, there could be more or less items in the list.  Beside each textbox there is a remove option. I can get the selected textbox to be removed from the container div no problem, but what I need to be able to do is then rename the remaining textboxes.

So if I remove `tb_2`, I'm not left with `tb_1` and `tb_3`, but rather `tb_1` and `tb_2`

Can this be done and if so how?

Comment: do you really need to call the textfields tb_1? or would tb[] work for you too? that would automatically adjust the number in the Postdata

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in some function and call that function after deleting element.

Try this, [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yrhEu/3/)

```
 $('#cartArea').children('input[type=text]').each(function(){

    this.name ='tb_' + eval($(this).index()+1);
    //alert( this.name)
  });​
```

Comment: trying this, I can change the id ok but the name is not changing

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal very simply like following:

```
$('#cartArea input[type=text]').attr('id', function(){
  return 'tb_' + $(this).index();  // change id
}).attr('name', function() {
  return 'tb_' + $(this).index();  // change name
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ekUty/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Afer you remove, you can run this code to rename them:

```
$('input[id^=tb_]').each(function(i, v){ this.name = 'tb_' + i; });
```

Answer (score 0):

After deletion you can loop through remaining element and change there name `attr`

Sample HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="tb_1" name="tb_1" /><span>remove</span>
<input type="text" id="tb_2" name="tb_2" /><span>remove</span>
<input type="text" id="tb_3" name="tb_3" /><span>remove</span>​
```

Sample Code:

```
jQuery('span').click(function(){
   jQuery(this).prev().remove();
   jQuery(this).remove();
    jQuery('input').each(function(index){
       jQuery(this).attr('name','tb_' + (index +1));   
    });
});​
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/ekUty/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like others responses because they either used the costly input[id^=] selector, the wordy input[type=text] selector, didn't account for i-being 0 based or didn't set the name attribute.

You can run this code after removal to rename the textboxes.

```
$('#cartArea input:text').each(function(i){ this.id = this.name = 'tb_' + (i + 1); });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HT6gS/

Answer (score 0):

No need for a quirky javascript solution here.

Just do it like:

```
<input type="text" id="tb_1" name="tb[]" />
<input type="text" id="tb_2" name="tb[]" />
<input type="text" id="tb_3" name="tb[]" />
```

Server side it is accessible via `$_GET['tb']` which is an array. So `$_GET['tb'][0]`, `$_GET['tb'][1]` and `$_GET['tb'][2]` representing your data if you sent 3 inputs to the server.